# What does 水をこざく mean?

Tags: meaning, words, dialects

I was reading something and saw the following lines spoken by an old male artist:

> 船が、水の下の者どもに気を配っていて大海原を往けるだろうか？
>
> 芸術も、人生も、しょせん水もの…
>
> 水を**こざいて**浮き上がった者だけが勝つのだ！

Someone else then responds:

> キレイな言葉でボヤかしてやがるが、『他人なんて踏み台だ』って意味じゃねーか。

This was all overlaid upon the following image:
[image]

I have no idea what  水を**こざく** means. The only thing I can find is maybe it's [dialectal](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/dialect/1148/m9u/%E6%96%B0%E6%BD%9F/), but that doesn't seem to make sense because if you're walking/treading (歩く) in water are you really 浮き上がる (floating) on top of water? What kind of image am I supposed to be seeing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/dialect/1148/m0u/) it's something like "to wade through." Without further context, it sounds like it's some kind of "sink or swim" implication.

Comment: +1, I did not know this word, but こざく seems to be used [from Hokkaido](https://ameblo.jp/fusigina-mori/entry-12025698308.html) to Nigata [to Shizuoka](http://cpg.music.coocan.jp/shitadaben.htm) in the sense of かきわけて進む or "to plow through" (e.g., 笹原をこざいてタケノコを採る).

Comment: Right. I used "wade" since water is involved. But if you're wading, then you're walking, so there's no question of "floating." I think we'd need more context to find a better translation.

Comment: @MarcAdler I added a bit more context

Comment: So “sink or swim” was right. My guess is こざく might simply mean something like “paddle” (ie みずをかく) in whatever dialect the writer’s speaking in.